# Hibernate:how to make entity class with all database fields automatically

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a project with MySQL,Hibernate,Java,GWT

I am making an entity class where i am making each and every field as per the fields in mysql
like there is a table UserInfo with fields ,id,name,password,and many other fields in MySQL

now when i am making an entity class in java/hibernate 
I have to create each field i.e id,name,password and others with my hand

I was just wondering if there's a way with which my entity class automatically detects all fields which are in my Database table and make all the fields in java itself and link them with the database fields.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hibernate has a property called "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto".

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto
>
> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL
>   to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop,
>   the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed
>   explicitly.
>
> e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

you can set the proper value when you start creating your sessionfactory. then you will see the tables were created in your datastore, of course, the table creation was based on your entity classes.

if you want to generate java classes (entities) from your database table. you may want to check hibernate reverse engineering out:

http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.M5/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html).